# How to Fix Echo command nested in if statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a script that will create another batch script. However this code will not run properly, immediately exiting as soon as the if statement is evaluated.

```
set yes=yes
pause


IF /I %yes% == yes (
    ECHO REM Music>>mf.bat
    ECHO FOR /f %%i in (C:\CopyToRoot\MusicFileAndLocation.txt) do set MusicFile=%%i>>mf.bat    
)`
```

However if the second line in the if statement is removed the code executes without issue.

What am I doing wrong? is there something I am missing about the echo statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "yes=yes"
Pause

If /I "%yes%"=="yes" (
    >"mf.bat" (
        Echo @Echo Off
        Echo Rem Music
        Echo For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%%%A In ("C:\CopyToRoot\MusicFileAndLocation.txt"^) Do Set "MusicFile=%%%%A"
    )
)
```

Double the percents and escape any internal closing parentheses.

Comment: This worked, it seems that the caret is what was missing from my code. When I added that it functioned as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the code block with a bit of effort, however, it is much simpler to get rid of the block and simply call a label. Also, the batch file will consume the `%` so you need to double them in order to redirect the string correctly to file.

```
@echo off
set yes=yes
pause

IF /I "%yes%"=="yes" call :final
goto :eof
:final
echo REM Music>mf.bat
echo FOR /f %%%%i in (C:\CopyToRoot\MusicFileAndLocation.txt) do set MusicFile=%%%%i>>mf.bat
```

Note I use single redirect on the first `rem` line to overwrite the file, else it will append each time you run the code, if that was the intention, simply do double redirect `>>`